# How to get the class name of the data model in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-modeling

Using this data model code in Angular:

```
export class Car {
  brand: string;
  year: number;
  nameOfModel() => {
    // I need return here the name of class as a string: 'Car'
  }
}
```

Can I somehow get back the name of the class as a string?

Comment: @KristófTóth : how is this working inside of the class if the model has a 'name' attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
export class Car {
    brand: string;
    year: number;
    nameOfModel: string = () => {
        return Car.name
    }
}
```